# Multiple Submit Button with Jquery submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have two buttons of type submit in a form

```
 <button type="submit" id="submitBtn" name="submitBtn" value="Save">Save</button>
 <button type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Print">Print</button>
```

In the controller action, I have

```
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Report(Report model, string submitBtn)
 {
    switch(submitBtn)
    {
        case "Save": ...
                     break;
        case "Print": ..
                     break;
    }
 }
```

Above code works perfectly fine.

However, now I need to do some client side validation on the click on Save button. So in jquery I added

```
 $('#submitBtn').click(function (e) { // id of the Save button
        e.preventDefault();
        // do validation and if all good then submit
            $('#reportform').submit();
 });
```

Whats happening here is that when form is submitted, its hitting the controller action correctly however the value passed to the argument string variable submitBtn is null

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Report(Report model, string submitBtn) <-- submitBtn is null
```

Any ideas why this happening? Please let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: You're not submitting with a button, so it's not being passed - ie submitBtn *is* null as you initiated the submit via code, not via a button

Comment: @freedomn-m I dont know if that should make a difference as that button is still being submitted. Anyhow, is there a solution to this if you could suggest?

Comment: Not sure of solution, would need to search SO.  "*as that button is still being submitted* - no, it's not, because you have two with name submitBtn, so which should it be when you do `$("form").submit()`?  The button isn't submitting, it was just clicked, not submitted.   You could try listening to the `submit` event rather than the button click, then it would know which button was used to submit.

Comment: If you listen to submit, then call the original submit with `$("reportform")[0],submit()` (note the extra `[0]`) otherwise you just re-call the jquery submit event - the `[0]` ensures you call the DOM submit() method, not the jquery submit() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before submitting the form you must append `submitBtn` to the form to send value to action.

```
$('#submitBtn').click(function (e) { // id of the Save button
        e.preventDefault();
        // do validation and if all good then submit

        $('#reportform').append("<input type='hidden' name='submitValue' value='Save' />");
        $('#reportform').submit();
});
```

and add Id for btnPrint

```
$('#printBtn').click(function (e) { // id of the Save button
    e.preventDefault();
    // do validation and if all good then submit

    $('#reportform').append("<input type='hidden' name='submitValue' value='Print' />");
    $('#reportform').submit();
});
```